# How to Backup a GETH synced full node?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, backup

I was able to sync a complete GETH fast node but the server crashed and the node did not work. So, now I am downloading again. But I have worries that the samething can happen again. My question is:

- How do I backup my Ethereum full node? Should I use rsync to copy all the chaindata to a separate location so that if the server crashes I can use the backup chaindata again?

Comment: Yes you can do it.

Comment: Would this work "on the fly", that is, while the synchronization is running? What would the be the `rsync` parameters to pass?